# ValueError: [E143] Labels for component 'tagger' not initialized

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I've been following this [tutorial](https://newscatcherapi.com/blog/train-custom-named-entity-recognition-ner-model-with-spacy-v3) to create a custom NER. However, I keep getting this error:
`ValueError: [E143] Labels for component 'tagger' not initialized. This can be fixed by calling add_label, or by providing a representative batch of examples to the component's` initialize `method.`

This is how I defined the spacy model:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from tqdm import tqdm

nlp = spacy.blank("ro") # load a new spacy model
source_nlp = spacy.load("ro_core_news_lg")
nlp.tokenizer.from_bytes(source_nlp.tokenizer.to_bytes())
nlp.add_pipe("tagger", source=source_nlp)

doc_bin = DocBin() # create a DocBin object
```

Comment: That tutorial looks kind of weird. Normally if you just want to re-use the pretrained tagger you would train an NER model *without* the tagger and then add it by sourcing later. Maybe take a look at the official spaCy course, which covers training an NER model in detail? https://course.spacy.io/en/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just meet the same problem. The picture of setting the config file is misleading you.
If you just want to run through the tutrital, you can set the config file like this.
[only click the check box on ner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJFd.png)